# Android image animation - How to animate a series of images.

Tags: android, android-animation

So I can basically animate an ImageView using the ObjectAnimation and AnimationSet classes.  However, now I want to do something more complex.

Say I have a basic face, face, mouth, and eyes, originally all of which are ImageView's in a FrameLayout.  I want to be able to to animate the face as a whole and individual items - for example tilt the head and raise an eyebrow.  I have found that I can't apply the animations to a FrameLayout as a whole.

Please could someone point me in the direction of the right approach for this task? :)

Comment: Mean, you want to move the imageview's like eyebrow??

Comment: yeah i want to move or rotate them as a group and individually

Comment: First start animation method to your image1, and apply animation listener to that one(image1). In the animationEnd method, again you start the image2.startAnimation. It seems to be animated images like a series.

Answer (score 0):

You Just Apply `image1.startAnimation(animOne);`
and apply Animation listener: 
In onAnimationEnd method, you just start one more image animation.

```
AnimationListener  smallAnimOrderOne = new AnimationListener()
    {

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            imageSmallAnim.startAnimation(smallOrderTwo);
            //System.out.println("me in end");

        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //System.out.println("me in repesat");
        }

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };
```

Comment: Thanks, thats kinda what I'm already doing.  But i can see that this will get very complex with more animations.  And it would be good to animate the images as one to avoid them getting out of sync.

Comment: Yes, It was little bit complicated compare to IOS Animation Path animation.